# Unable to pass the string variable to Sprite in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm having problem with the strings in cocos2dx & C++. I want to pass the variable background to `Sprite::create(background)` however, I get an error. If it was in java the following code will work, but since I'm not used to C++ it may be different. Plus, if it was a int how will I pass it ? How will I be able to solve this? Some tips or samples will be great! I will love to hear from you!

```
void GameLayer::initBackground()
{
    UserDefault *_userDef = UserDefault::getInstance();
    //int型
    auto _int =_userDef->getIntegerForKey("back");
    auto string  background = "Background1.png";
    if (_int == 0) {
       background = "Background2.png";
    } 
    auto bgForCharacter = Sprite::create(background);
    bgForCharacter->setAnchorPoint(Point(0, 1));
    bgForCharacter->setPosition(Point(0, WINSIZE.height));
    addChild(bgForCharacter, ZOrder::BgForCharacter);

    auto bgForPuzzle = Sprite::create("Background2.png");
    bgForPuzzle->setAnchorPoint(Point::ZERO);
    bgForPuzzle->setPosition(Point::ZERO);
    addChild(bgForPuzzle, ZOrder::BgForPuzzle);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto userDefault=UserDefault::getInstance();

int value=userDefault->getIntegerForKey("back"); //find value for back if exist then it return that value else return 0

auto sprite = Sprite::create(value==0?"Background2.png":"Background1.png");
sprite->setPosition(100, 100);
this->addChild(sprite, 0);
```

When you want to change your background just put any value rather than 0

```
UserDefault::getInstance()->setIntegerForKey("back", 1);
```